# How to parse Jsonelement to Array?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

Trying to parse this data "boxes" into Int Array in Kotlin.

```
{"result":{"boxes":[[[345,554],[417,554],[417,638],[345,638]]]}}
```

having problem to parse it with TypeToken using Data model class

Data Model class looks like this

```
 data class boxResult(var result: JsonObject, var boxes: Array<Int>)
 data class boxes(var boxes:String, var boxresult: Array<Int>)
```

and TypeToken looks like this

```
 var type: Array<DataModel.boxes> = Gson().fromJson(it.result ,object : TypeToken<Array<DataModel.boxes>>(){}.type)
```

keep failing to parse JsonElement as Int Array ... need help
Thanks

Comment: I don't know Kotlin but it seems your JSON doesn't match to your model. In the `boxes` there are 3 '['. It means you have to define 1 more level to reach to Array of Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this shall do

```
data class Base (

    @SerializedName("result") val result : Result
)

data class Result (

        @SerializedName("boxes") val boxes : List<List<List<Int>>>
    )
```